# how to count two same property with different values in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

first, i should say that im new to `mongoDB` and `mongoose ODM`. my question: each document of my documents is something like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6353f73c97588e3864eaa635"
  },
  "text": "test!",
  "date": "10/22/2022, 2:52:52 PM",
  "isCompleted": false
}
```

they have `isComplete` property that can be `true` or `false`.
now i want to count documents with `isComplete: true` or `isComplete: false` in just one query. and i want something like this result:

```
{completed: 4, notCompleted: 6}
```

i found that `mongoose` has a method called `count` and `countDocuments`. but with these methodes, i can do what i want in 2 queries. like this:

```
//body of an async function      
const completed = await mongoose.count({ isCompleted: true });
const notCompleted = await mongoose.count({ isCompleted: false });
```

i can not do something like this:

```
//body of an async function      
const counts = await mongoose.count({ isCompleted: true, isCompleted: false });
```

i searched a lot about this, but i couldnt find any solution. so whats your solution? do you have any suggestion? thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate with conditional grouping, but I'm not sure whether that will be faster than 2 separated count queries in a collection with big record set since you will essentially be loading ALL your records in the pipeline.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "completed": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$completed",
                true
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "incomplete": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$completed",
                false
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "totalCount": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    },
    
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/RynsVsi9BEJ

PS: aggregation always return an array, so you can use e.g. `results[0].completed` to get number of completed records.

Comment: thanks for your answer! it worked. my app is small but i want it to have good performance. because of it i thought that it should be better to do this in one query not two. and you dont know what solution has better performance... thank you again.

Comment: You can do 2 queries, using `Promise.all`, so it both run at the same time.